# Unable to install FOSRestBundle with Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, fosrestbundle, symfony5

I was trying to install FOSRestBundle on **Symfony 5** using composer but got the following error message:

> friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 2.7.1 requires symfony/config ^3.4|^4.3

Is it possible to manually install FOSRestBundle with Symfony 5; as it seems it will not be updated and instead API Platform will be maintained in future?

I don't want to use API Platform as it has lot of stuff not required by my project.

Comment: If that bundle is not updated to Symfony 5 yet then you could either wait for them to update it. Or you could create a fork of the bundle and update it to be SF5 ready yourself. Other than that there really aren't any good options I'm afraid.

Comment: An [issue](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/2043#issuecomment-582550337) is already open to support SF5.

Comment: Which part of that error message are unclear? If the bundle is not yet compatible, have you tried to check with them about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks GrenierJ, an [issue](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/2043#issuecomment-580830492) is already open and as per **xabbuh**, the master now serves for the development of FOSRestBundle 3.0. Its version constraints already allow Symfony 5 components. I tried to install the dev-master using `composer require --dev friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle:dev-master` and it successfully installed. Its under development so all of its features may not be compatible with Symfony 5.

Answer (score 4):

FOSRestBundle development has not been abandoned.

But Symfony 5 support [is not expected until version 3](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/2043#issuecomment-582550337).

You can check the progress [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/milestone/9). As you can see there is no due date yet.

So you either continue using FOSRestBundle with Symfony 4.4 (which is perfectly acceptable, 4.4 it's a long term release and it's not going anywhere), or you **need** Symfony 5; you either look for alternatives to FOSRestBundle or run a pre-release version (with the risks that it entail).

Comment: [Version 3](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/2043#issuecomment-638976888) is available now.